# What is the status of Miux?

Tags: distribution-choice

[Microsoft Announces Its Own Linux OS](http://itsfoss.com/microsoft-announces-linux-os/), on *It's F.O.S.S.*, **April 1, 2015**.

I cannot find it on distrowatch. Was this a hoax, or is this a real, living distro that can be downloaded, tested?

Comment: Why accept as an answer a link to something unrelated to the April 1st, 2015 event, it makes it unclear what you are actually asking about. Is it about the April1st announcement or not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, it was published on April 1, 2015 - [April Fools' Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Fools'_Day). They produce other jokes on April 1<sup>st</sup>, like [Linus Torvalds To Join Microsoft To Head Windows 9 Project](http://itsfoss.com/linus-torvalds-to-join-microsoft/).

Comment: In addition, at the end of the page there is a [Know more about Microsoft’s Linux OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Fools'_Day) button that links [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Fools'_Day) "April Fools' Day" page.

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft Linux](http://www.mslinux.org) is a similar effort. 
The Overview on the home page states,

> Microsoft Linux provides all the power of the Linux Operating System
> with the ease of use you’ve come to expect from Microsoft Products.

This is augmented with a list of features, pricing information,
quotes from industry and government leaders,
useful links, and news bites regarding other Microsoft projects.

> Thanks to [user80998](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/107403/user80998)
> for posting this the first time.

## ;-)

Answer (score -4):

It's not miux, it's Azure Cloud Switch, which is based on Linux!

http://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/09/18/microsoft_has_developed_its_own_linux_repeat_microsoft_has_developed_its_own_linux/

Comment: Wow. That has absolutely nothing to do with Miux hoax published on itsfoss.com.

Comment: @Christopher You're right, it cannot be related as this announcement came several months after what the OP asked about.